# Android App exits when request Runtime Permissions

Tags: android, permissions

In the program below I ask for SMS permission before sending a message.

At first App execution, when the message request is confirmed, the permission are checked and, if missing, a pop up requesting the user to allow the app is issued.

When this pop up is issued, the app is moved in background.

I found many topics about this issue but no fixes for my problem. E.g. the nohistory entry is missing in the manifest.

```
private void checkForSmsPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        return;

    } else {
        // Permission already granted. Enable the SMS button.
        return;
    }
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,  String[] permissions,  int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS)  {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

public void send_command (String text){

    checkForSmsPermission();


    //Get the SmsManager instance and call the sendTextMessage method to send message
    SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(recipient_number, null, text, null,null);


}
```

Comment: what is your logcat saying?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are calling following method anyways.

```
SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
 sms.sendTextMessage(recipient_number, null, text, null,null);
```

You should only call them if you are sure that you have the permission else your app will crash.
Its always recommended to call these method on success of permission validation. but in your case it will get call whether the user provided the permission or not.

Comment: Thanks, but still some doubts. Before sending the message I ask for permission.... is the method called anyway? Can I make this method wait for permissions?

Comment: no you are calling ` checkForSmsPermission();` but you are not sure that you got the permission or not and anyways, till the user will see the permission dialog anyway your sms.sendTextMessage will get called and will crash

Comment: you need to wrap it in `onRequestPermissionsResult` for 1st time and in else part of `checkForSmsPermission` for next time onwards

Comment: Please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Thanks a lot. Clear. I'll try.

Comment: let me know if you have any further problem I am happy to help